# Porting SSL application from Java to C#

Tags: c#, java, ssl, .net-4.0, cryptography

I'm porting a [java client](https://github.com/pcgod/mumble-android) for [mumble](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/) to C# and I've hit a bit of a brick wall.

In java, the SSL socket is initiated like so:

```
final SSLContext ctx_ = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ctx_.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new LocalSSLTrustManager() }, null);
final SSLSocketFactory factory = ctx_.getSocketFactory();
final SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(hostAddress, port);
sslSocket.setUseClientMode(true);
sslSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] { "TLSv1" });
sslSocket.startHandshake();
```

I've ported this to C# like this:

```
return ssl = new SslStream(netStream, false, (a, b, c, d) => true); //For now, accept any cert
ssl.AuthenticateAsClient(serverName);
```

Now, this does actually establish a connection, but it's using AES128 and the [mumble protocol](https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumble/blob/master/doc/mumble-protocol.pdf) requires AES256 so the server appears to then ignore anything I send on this socket.

Is my code correctly ported? And is there a way to force C# to use AES256 for this connection?

Comment: Why would the server accept AES-128 connections if the protocol disallows it? How do you know your java client was using AES-256 and how do you know you C# client is using AES-128?

Comment: The SSL stream has a property which tells you the type of encryption used, in this case AES, with strength 128. It turns out that the problem I was having was not the server ignoring things, it was bad documentation of packet layouts. However, I would still like to know if there is a way to force the encryption to 256 bit.

Comment: Sure thing, just enable only those cipher suites on the server that use AES-256. You can do the same thing at the client, but that might be slightly harder. A quick Google found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91304/nets-sslstream-is-always-negotiating-to-the-least-secure-cipher-i-have-how-ca

Answer (score 0):

No your code is fine, By defualt, however, windows appears not to enable AES256 support because TLS 1.2 is not enabled.  Java uses its own SSL implementation which evidently does support it. As a result, when negotiating with the server usng c#, AES128 is selected because its the strongest cipher windows supports by default.

According to this [site](http://derek858.blogspot.com/2010/06/enable-tls-12-aes-256-and-sha-256-in.html) running the following powershell script should enable AES256 in TLS and fix your issue. I'd make sure its not doing anything funny before running it.

```
# Enables TLS 1.2 on Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7
# June 27, 2010
# Version 1.2
# These keys do not exist so they need to be created prior to setting values.

md "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2"

md "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server"

md "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client"

# Enable TLS 1.2 for client and server SCHANNEL communications

new-itemproperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server" -name "Enabled" -value 1 -PropertyType "DWord"

new-itemproperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server" -name "DisabledByDefault" -value 0 -PropertyType "DWord"

new-itemproperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" -name "Enabled" -value 1 -PropertyType "DWord"

new-itemproperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" -name "DisabledByDefault" -value 0 -PropertyType "DWord"

# Disable SSL 2.0 (PCI Compliance)
md "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server"

new-itemproperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server" -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType "DWord"
```